# How to find the lastIndexOf for multiple characters?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if there is already decimal place after the last operator used in a mathematic expression. Since the expression can change, the final operator can be different.

```
if (val === "." && result.includes('.', result.lastIndexOf('+' || '-' || '/' || '*'))) {
 setResult(result)
}
```

This is supposed to check if the current button pressed (val) is a decimal and if the current expression (result) already includes a decimal after the last operator, then to not add in a second decimal.

```
result.lastIndexOf('+' || '-' || '/' || '*')
```

This code currently only works for the + operator and does not look at the other 3 operators, -, /, & *. How would you have lastIndexOf look at the actual final operator used?

For example if the expression was 4+5-3, the above code returns the + before the 5 as the final operator used and not the - before the 3

Comment: What exactly do you want. It is not so clear. Please be specific and add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Can you clarify what you really want?

Comment: I think OP is writing a calculator

Comment: yes, I am currently making a calculator, I've edited my question to hopefully make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be overkill, but you can also use regular expression

```js
let regex = /(?:\+|\-|\*|\/)(?!.*(?:\+|\-|\*|\/))/;
console.log(regex.exec("4+5-3").index);
console.log(regex.exec("1+2-3*4/5").index);
```

You can even integrate your goal to the regular expression. This example checks if there is a `.` after the last +,-,*,/:

```js
function canAppendDot(expression)
{
  return !/(?:\.)(?!.*(?:\+|\-|\*|\/))/.test(expression)
}

console.log(canAppendDot("4+5.5-"));
console.log(canAppendDot("4+5.5-6"));
console.log(canAppendDot("4+5.5-6."));
console.log(canAppendDot("4+5.5-6.5"));
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I tried using a regular expression before but was replacing result.lastIndexof(regex) with regex.exec(result), which made me believe I was on the wrong path. The correct way to do it was to combine the two like so result.lastIndexOf(regex.exec(result)). I was also missing the lookaheads you used.
Your regular expression is correct, but I was also able to shorten it a bit to /(?:\W)(?!.*(?:\W))/. This is more generic for any non letter character but still works inside my scope.
Now I need to figure out and understand the lookahead assertions that you used for this expression.

Comment: @Blistighast check my updated example, you can directly check if there is a decimal point after the last operator directly within the regular expression :)

Comment: Regex are so versatile. I've been trying to make sure I fully understand the one you provided. The 1st group (?:\+|\-|\*|\/) is the operator to be checked and the 2nd group (?!.*(?:\+|\-|\*|\/)) is the negative lookahead. The 2nd group is what checks if there are any other operators after the 1st group? Does the .* mean there can be any other characters between them? And finally why should both groups be non-capturing vs capturing? I tried (\+|\-|\*|\/)(?!.*(\+|\-|\*|\/)) and got similar results. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you have got it right. Using non-capturing group is just my personal preference. Yes you can still use capturing group and ignore the captured result. I usually use capturing group only when I really need to extract the content, and use non-capturing group when I don't care the content so that when I later want to edit the regex to capture something, I don't need to go back and change all the capturing group I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

You could tweek `lastIndexOf` a littlebit to achive your target. `lastIndexOf` returns the index of the last occurance of a character in a string. Since you have to mach multiple operators, you can use the below logic

- Generate the list of characters that you need to check the last index. Here I have used `['+', '-', '*', '/']` list.
- Run a map function against ths list and generate the array of last ndices of each operator.
- Find the Maximum values from the generated array with some logic. I have mad use of `Math.max`.
- The maximum in this list will be the last index of the list of operators that you wish to find from the expression.

```js
const result = "15.36+30-5";
const characterList = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
const indexList = characterList.map(character => result.lastIndexOf(character));
console.log(`Last index ${Math.max(...indexList)}`);
```